# Filling the space between two circles

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have prepared a code in which there are two circles. I want to fill the space between them with the same color. Here is my code

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{graphicx}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{color}{{red}{black}}
\foreach \a in {1,...,90}{
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\x}{0}{50}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\y}{0}{50}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\r}{3}{3}
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{color}
    \pgfpathcircle{
    \pgfpoint{\x }{\y }}{\r mm}
    \color{\c!70!white}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\c!20!black}
    \pgfusepath{stroke, fill}
}



% shape of the nucleus
\fill[opacity=0.15,rotate=30] (0,0) ellipse (4 and 3);

% field around the nucleus
\fill[opacity=0.15,color=blue] (0.8,0.8) circle (1.7);

% the single neutron or proton
\fill[black] (-1.5,-1.5) circle (0.3); 
\fill[red] (-1.5,-1.2) arc (90:-90:0.3); 

% field around the single particle
\fill[opacity=0.15,color=blue] (-1.5,-1.5) circle (0.7);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The result of this code is

[image]

but I want to have something like

[image]

How can I do it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would use backgrounds and `tangent cs`, which comes with the `calc` library, for that.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{color}{{red}{black}}
\foreach \a in {1,...,90}{
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\x}{0}{50}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\y}{0}{50}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\r}{3}{3}
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{color}
    \pgfpathcircle{
    \pgfpoint{\x }{\y }}{\r mm}
    \color{\c!70!white}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\c!20!black}
    \pgfusepath{stroke, fill}
}


\begin{scope}[on background layer]
% shape of the nucleus
\fill[white!85!black,rotate=30] (0,0) ellipse (4 and 3);

% field around the nucleus
\node[circle,fill=blue!15,minimum size=3.4cm] (A) at (0.8,0.8) {};

% field around the single particle
\node[circle,fill=blue!15,minimum size=1.4cm] (B) at (-1.5,-1.5){};

\fill[fill=blue!15]  (tangent cs:node=A,point={(B.center)},solution=1) 
to[bend right=25] (tangent cs:node=B,point={(A.center)},solution=2)
 -- (tangent cs:node=B,point={(A.center)},solution=1) to[bend right=25]
 (tangent cs:node=A,point={(B.center)},solution=2) --
 cycle;

% the single neutron or proton
\fill[black] (-1.5,-1.5) circle (0.3); 
\fill[red] (-1.5,-1.2) arc (90:-90:0.3); 

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A second possibility, which keeps your opacity, is to use a `transparency group`.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\pgfmathdeclarerandomlist{color}{{red}{black}}
\foreach \a in {1,...,90}{
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\x}{0}{50}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\y}{0}{50}
    \pgfmathrandominteger{\r}{3}{3}
    \pgfmathrandomitem{\c}{color}
    \pgfpathcircle{
    \pgfpoint{\x }{\y }}{\r mm}
    \color{\c!70!white}
    \pgfsetstrokecolor{\c!20!black}
    \pgfusepath{stroke, fill}
}



% shape of the nucleus
\fill[opacity=0.15,rotate=30] (0,0) ellipse (4 and 3);
% the single neutron or proton
\fill[black] (-1.5,-1.5) circle (0.3); 
\fill[red] (-1.5,-1.2) arc (90:-90:0.3); 

\begin{scope}[transparency group,opacity=0.15]
% field around the nucleus
\node[circle,fill=blue,minimum size=3.4cm] (A) at (0.8,0.8) {};

% field around the single particle
\node[circle,fill=blue,minimum size=1.4cm] (B) at (-1.5,-1.5){};

\fill[blue]  (tangent cs:node=A,point={(B.center)},solution=1) 
to[bend right=25] (tangent cs:node=B,point={(A.center)},solution=2)
 -- (tangent cs:node=B,point={(A.center)},solution=1) to[bend right=25]
 (tangent cs:node=A,point={(B.center)},solution=2) -- cycle;

\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]